# Help turning xpath result into formatted string

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I am trying to parse an xml feed using xpath. The feed contains categories that look like this:

```
<categories>
<category id="6">Category 6</category>
<category id="12">Category 12</category>
<category id="19">Category 19</category>
</categories>
```

I currently using the path 'categories' to select all child nodes of  which returns "Category 6Category 12Category 19" in string format. I would like the output to be like "Category 6, Category 12, Category 19" instead. How can I achieve this? I looked at xpath functions but nothing seems to fit this task.

I'm using this with Drupal's [xpath parser module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser)

Comment: You should specify programming language you use to parse the XML and how you display XPath result.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a confirmation that this problem cannot be solved in pure XPath 1.o and for an extremely short and easy XPath 2.0 one-liner solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure XPath is:

```
concat(categories/category[id="6"],', ',
       categories/category[id="12"],', ',
       categories/category[id="19"])
```

But it's not going to be very useful if you need something dynamic, I mean if you don't know `categories` children *a priori*.

For a dynamic selection use:

```
string-join(categories/*,', ')
```

or

```
string-join(/categories/*,', ')
```

depending on the context.

Comment: This is essentially what I want but I need it to be dynamic.

Comment: Ok, try the other solution provided in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should use the /categories/category xpath to select the category nodes and then enumerate the nodeset and display the content of each node, followed by the comma (except the last node). The exact code depends on the technology you use.

Comment: Is it possible using only xpath syntax?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case of statically unknown XML document the wanted result cannot be produced using only pure XPath 1.0 -- some help from the programming language that is hosting it is needed.

**A simple and pure XPath 2.0 solution for this is**:

```
string-join(/*/*,', ')
```